# What does a midi-chlorian look like?

Tags: star-wars

### Is there any canon information on what a midi-chlorian looks like?

This question is based on the fact that if it can be measured, it can seen. Non existent things cannot be measured and therefore cannot be seen.

In Wookieepedia a [Midi-chlorian](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian) was:

> Midi-chlorians were microscopic, intelligent lifeforms that live
>   within the cells of all living beings.

Microscopic does not mean unable to be seen, and in the advanced technology when Star-wars took place, they surely would have been able to observed as Qui-Gon did measure them with Obi-Wan Kenobi.

### So what does a Midi-chlorian look like?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian/Legends Don't know if it's a fan made or an official representation

Comment: @Saphirel, looks good to me, make it an answer.

Comment: Mitochondrion, but add ethereal glow and tron-lines?

Comment: _"This question is based on the fact that if it can be measured, it can seen"_ What does gravity look like, Kylo?

Comment: @Radhil, err, the exert says they are microscopic lifeforms, is gravity a microscopic life form?

Comment: @KyloRen, no. Matter isn't a microscopic life form either. (Though we have  observed lifeforms composed of matter.)

Comment: Sorry, but the premise is completely wrong. Many things that can be measured can't be seen. Apart from the obvious things such as gravity and velocity, anything smaller than the wavelength of light can't be "seen". It *can* be detected and measured and manipulated but we can only "see" what our eyes can deal with and those, by definition, only deal with visible light and can't detect very small things. So any particle the size of an atom or smaller can never be seen, only detected.

Comment: Pretty sure they look like early 90s electronic music equipment covered in bleach.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, [Here's how gravity looks like](http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/ns_gw_art.jpg).

Comment: Looks to me like a *really* bad idea

Comment: Bigger than a mini-chlorian, smaller than a maxi-chlorian.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following image appears in [*Star Wars Blueprints: The Ultimate Collection*.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Blueprints:_The_Ultimate_Collection) Despite being a **non-canon** source, it appears to be the best representation of a midi-chlorian that we have.

The middle panel is a close-up. The lower picture gives some idea of scale (inside a red blood cell).

[image]
[image]

George Lucas offered the following description

> "*Midi-chlorians are a loose depiction of mitochondria, which are
> necessary components for cells to divide. They probably had
> something--which will come out someday--to do with the beginnings of
> life and how one cell decided to become two cells with a little help
> from this other little creature who came in, without whom life
> couldn't exist. And it's really a way of saying we have hundreds of
> little creatures who live on us, and without them, we all would die.
> There wouldn't be any life. They are necessary for us; we are
> necessary for them. Using them in the metaphor, saying society is the
> same way, says we all must get along with each other.*"
>
> <sub><sup>[E! Online - From the Star Wars Flu to His Beloved Pit Droids, George Lucas Talks Phantom Phenom](https://web.archive.org/web/19991103105353/http://www.eonline.com/News/More/lucas5.html)</sup></sub>

You can see the similarity between a mitochondrion and a midi-chlorian below.

[image]
<sub><sup>Electron Microscope picture courtesy of Keith R. Porter</sup></sub>

Comment: Midi-Chlorians are the powerhouse of the cell...

Comment: @Tratto - That joke works better with a [link](http://www.pbslearningmedia.org/resource/tdc02.sci.life.cell.mitochondria/the-powerhouse-of-the-cell/). Not everyone here is a Yank.

Comment: As someone who studies the origin of life as my profession, I would like to react to the George Lucas quote in the following manner: Aaaaarrrrggggrgghh. Only eucaryotes have mitochondria. Bacteria and archaea don't have them, and they existed for a long time before eucaryotes like us. It's not at all true that "life couldn't exist" without mitochondria, though it does seem that *multicellular* life is pretty difficult without them. (This is not in any way a criticism of your answer.)

Comment: @Nathaniel, "all life" could be an abbreviation of "all multicellular life". For my purposes, the statement would be close enough.

Comment: @Nathaniel it tickles my fancy that not only do midichlorians annoy Star Wars fans, now they also annoy biologists.

Comment: @WayneWerner as a biologist and a Star Wars fan, I can assure you I am doubly annoyed :) Oh, and don't get me started on zobie viruses. . .

Comment: That awkward moment when you realize Star Wars ripped off [Parasite Eve...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasite_Eve_(video_game))

Comment: [Midichloria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midichloria) :)

Comment: @Nathaniel: That's not the part that bothers me.  Red blood cells in humans are really small, and that image in this answer shows midi-chlorians much smaller than those.  They are smaller than almost any prokaryote, and clearly smaller than mithochondria.

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/152631/4918 "Where did this George Lucas quote come from?" about that quote

Comment: @b_jonas - I've edited the original quote source into my answer

Answer (score 2):

In Wookieepedia you have [this picture.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian/Legends). Seems to be a good microscopic-thing representation.[image: midi-chlorian]

Comment: Wookiepedia is a largely-user-generated content that may or may not be canonical. You have to explain where Wikia page got the picture from and whether that source is canonical or fan-generated.

Comment: You should also give credit to its creator.

Comment: I reverse-searched this picture and found it only in fan-based websites. Feel free to edit my answer if you find it :)