# When did George Lucas compare midi-chlorians to mitochondria?

Tags: star-wars, george-lucas, midichlorians

It is *widely* reported online that the following quote is attributed to George Lucas:

> Midi-chlorians are a loose depiction of mitochondria, which are necessary components for cells to divide. They probably had something--which will come out someday--to do with the beginnings of life and how one cell decided to become two cells with a little help from this other little creature who came in, without whom life couldn't exist. And it's really a way of saying we have hundreds of little creatures who live on us, and without them, we all would die. There wouldn't be any life. They are necessary for us; we are necessary for them. Using them in the metaphor, saying society is the same way, says we all must get along with each other.

Yet I am unable to trace it back to where he said it.

I have also found several references to a 2005 Rolling Stone article that apparently has the exact quote, but the only [article](http://www.rollingstone.com/movies/news/george-lucas-and-the-cult-of-darth-vader-20050602) that I can find does not contain that quote.

The earliest I can find this quote is [2001](http://www.theforce.net/midichlorians/midi-what.asp) which many future pages link back to. It appears that it comes from an interview after the release of *The Phantom Menace*.

*note: it will probably take someone 30 seconds to find it even though I spent 45 min looking but I am at the limit of the time (and perhaps skill?) that I can spend on this. Thank you*

Comment: dunno - but midichlorians are now 'real' - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midichloria

Comment: "Which are necessary components for cells to divide" - ummm, their main function is to generate energy.  I suppose in an oblique way he may be right, because everything requires energy..... in any case, are you looking for confirmation so you will be justified in throat-punching him for screwing up the basic biological science in that statement?

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Well, I'm not really looking for confirmation if the quote is right in what it is saying. I just want to know where George Lucas said it. It seems like Midichlorian and Mitochondria share a lot of similarities, and I can accept that, no problem. I just thought it odd that it appears *difficult* to find where this quote originates, considering its importance to defining "the Force".

Comment: I know.  It just struck me as fundamentally and irritatingly stupid for him to say it like that, so I could not resist the snark.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Totally - you wouldn't believe the snark (and also vitriol) online surrounding this topic!

Comment: @Valorum That *is* weird. Would you mind posting the Starlog link when you get a moment? Thank you

Comment: OK. Weirdness resolved. It was ***two different transcription of the same interview***.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Found it.

The article was published in [E! Online on May 11, 1999](https://web.archive.org/web/19991103105353/http://www.eonline.com/News/More/lucas5.html) following a press conference with George Lucas and contains a more extensive quote (reproduced in its entirety below). Note that the author has transcribed midi-chlorians incorrectly, referring to them as *midichondrians*.

> ***Will you ever see the movie with an audience?***
>
> *I probably will at some point, but it'll be later in the summer. It's
> inevitable that one wants to do that, see what real people think about
> it.*
>
> ***Is there something about you that exposure in the media has changed, 60 Minutes and so forth?***
>
> *Again, I've been through these hoops a lot. Whenever a movie comes
> out, whether it's Star Wars or Howard the Duck, I end up on a lot of
> covers, and I end up with a lot of media presence for a period of
> time--with Howard the Duck, it was about 10 minutes, with Star Wars I
> expect it to be about three or four months. I'm assuming by fall
> things will have calmed down again, and I can go back to not having
> this much media attention. The great thing about living in San
> Francisco is it's a great cosmopolitan city, but you don't have a lot
> of people chasing you around all the time to get autographs and
> things. Every once in a while somebody comes up, but it's usually a
> little kid. It's a sophisticated environment. It's easier to live in.*
>
> ***I know you're saying Saturday-morning serial for kids, but I saw in this movie you're going from classic, heroic stuff into much more
> specifically Judeo-Christian ideas. Can you talk a little about where
> you see the meaning of the Star Wars movies going?***
>
> *Well, I'm confused. I've been very conscious about not making the
> movies religion specific. When I brought the first Star Wars movie
> out, it seemed most religions used it to demonstrate their own
> beliefs--not only Judeo-Christian but also Eastern. And in many cases,
> people have said they're much more Eastern than Western in nature. I'm
> a little curious as to why you decided this one was a little more like
> that.*
>
> ***The ideas of virgin birth, the freeing of slaves...***
>
> *Did you see Spartacus?*
>
> ***That's Western, too.***
>
> *Yes, that's Western, too. Actually the same thing has happened in
> China and in India, especially. The issue of Immaculate Conception is
> a motif that runs through all religions. It's a motif that runs
> through all stories about the local deity or the local hero. It's the
> same thing with Hercules. Most heroes are conceived in an unusual way.
> And in this particular case, it's actually not Immaculate Conception,
> it's conception by metaphor, I would say, more than anything else. I'm
> taking the idea of symbiotic relationships and trying to demonstrate
> it in a more concrete way. **Midichondrians are a loose depiction of
> mitochondria, which are necessary components for cells to divide. They
> probably had something--which will come out someday--to do with the
> beginnings of life and how one cell decided to become two cells with a
> little help from this other little creature who came in, without whom
> life couldn't exist. And it's really a way of saying we have hundreds
> of little creatures who live on us, and without them, we all would
> die. There wouldn't be any life.They are necessary for us; we are
> necessary for them. Using them in the metaphor, saying society is the
> same way, says we all must get along with each other.**  The planet is
> the same way. We must treat the other creatures on the planet with
> respect, otherwise the planet will die.*
>
> <sub><sup>[E! Online - From the Star Wars Flu to His Beloved Pit Droids, George Lucas Talks Phantom Phenom](https://web.archive.org/web/19990828081516/http://www.eonline.com/News/More/lucas.html?fd.thirds.gr)</sup></sub>

---

The interview was also carried in the **August** edition of [Starlog #265](https://archive.org/stream/starlog_magazine-265/265_djvu.txt). Note that the quote stops with a period in the Starlog article (downloadable [here](https://diz.srve.io/zines/Starlog/)) but continues with a comma and then the stuff about midi-chlorians in the article above. This wasn't a one-on-one interview but a press-conference (in which Starlog were in attendance) which would explain the difference in transcription.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe the quote was generated by the midi-chlorians?

Comment: "May the Force be with you" - Abraham Lincoln

Comment: @Valorum I did the same. I wonder how many more emails he'll have received today..

Comment: @Valorum Sorry, I meant that I'd done it 2 hours ago :/ Oh well!

Comment: ***The Immaculate Conception of Mary is totally different from the virginal conception and birth of Christ.*** Get it right, Lucas.